# Copy files to directory and add path name to file name

Tags: unix

I have multiple zip files that each contain files with the same name, but the zip files have unique names. What I want to do is put all the files with the same name from the multiple zips in a single directory, but preserve which zip they are from they are by adding the zip folder name to the filename. Additionally, the zips do not necessarily have the same folder structure within them - the files with the same names could be in any folder inside the zips (but I do not need to preserve the intermediate folder names).

For example, say I have

```
-> zip1 - folder1 - file1
                  - file2
-> zip2 - file1
        - file2
```

Then what I want is to get the following files in a directory together with concatenated names:

```
- zip1file1
- zip1file2
- zip2file1
- zip2file2
```

The 'folder1' doesn't *have* to be ignored, but I don't really care either way, the zip folder has the important information in the name.

So far, I have done

```
for zip in *.zip; do unzip "$zip" -d "${zip%.zip}"; done
```

to unzip all the zips into their own unique folders with the names I want to preserve. Then I can find a list of all the relevant files using 'find' from the directory containing all the unzipped files:

```
find . -name 'file1.m'
```

But I'm not sure how to move the results of this 'find' into a new directory, and add the name of the folder they're in to their file name.

Answer (score 0):

i will try my best

myfiles is the directory for the moved files.
is not a one-liner but should work

```
DEST="./myfiles"
mkdir -p $DEST
find zip* -type f | while read f
do
  mv $f $DEST/${f//'/'}
done
```

will do:

```
mv zip1/folder1/file2 ./myfiles/zip1folder1file2
mv zip1/folder1/file1 ./myfiles/zip1folder1file1
mv zip2/file2 ./myfiles/zip2file2
mv zip2/file1 ./myfiles/zip2file1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the myfiles folder is still empty after running this, and I get the `usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory` warning repeatedly